# Cannot building code using extension in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am having issue getting the following code to compile on Xcode6-beta.  This is the error I got: "1.   While emitting IR SIL function @top_level_code:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 :0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)"

Any idea what I did wrong?

```
import Foundation

class Thing : Printable {
    var name:String
    var description:String { return name }

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Thing {
    var nameWithArticle:String {
    return "a" + name
    }
}

let bigfoot = Thing(name: "BigFoot")
println(bigfoot.nameWithArticle)
```

Comment: another compiler bug.

Comment: wow, this is a bummer - had my fingers crossed as I fired up DP2 to check if it worked there yet, but no luck

Comment: @ackStOverflow same here - I've got a related bug with an extension and beta2 hasn't fixed it here either

Comment: Is there a radar submitted that I can reference?

Comment: Same here, stopping me from building Archive for my app